# Multiple components mutating a property subsequently (within a context) results in only one effective mutation

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-context, use-context

Let's say I have a context provider `CounterProvider` like so:

```
const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ count: 0 });

    const setCount = count => {
        typeof count === 'function' && (count = count(data.count));
        setData({ ...data, count });
    };

    return (
        <CounterContext.Provider value={{...data, setCount}}>
            {children}
        </CounterContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And a consumer `XComp`:

```
const XComp = () => {
    const {count, setCount} = useContext(CounterContext);
    useEffect(() => setCount(count_prev => ++count_prev));
    return <div>XComp</div>;
};
```

Now, if I use `XComp` 3 times (ex: **sample-xcomp-usage*), `CounterProvider` state will be `{count: 1}`. So, it *looks* like only the first call of `setData()` in `CounterProvider` becomes effective.

Now the question(s):

1. Why does only the first call to `setData()` *seem* to be effective?
2. How can I make every call to `setData()` effective?

**sample-xcomp-usage*:

```
<InstanceCounterProvider>
    <XComp />
    <XComp />
    <XComp />
</InstanceCounterProvider>
```

.............

Note:
While making this edit, I just realized the "why" and "how".

Answer to question 1:
Component's state changes via `setData()` are not necessarily applied immediately, rather **stored** for later update. So subsequent callee `setData()` does not normally see the changes. Causing the override of **stored** data. That is why only the first `setData()` *seems* to be effective.

Answer to question 2:
React provides an overload of `setState()` that takes a `callback` as the argument to produce the changed state. The callback is provided with **stored** data. So, it is necessary modify the `setCount()` inside `CountProvider` like so:

```
    const setCount = count => {
        setData(data_prev => {
            typeof count === 'function' && (count = count(data_prev.count));
            return { ...data_prev, count };
        };
    };
```